# Best way to cache data

Tags: .net, caching

I am in the process of figuring out a cache strategy for our current setup, currently have multiple web servers and wanted to know what is the best way to cache data in this environment. I have done research about MemCache and the native asp.net caching but wanted to get some feedback first. Should I go with a Linux box if I use MemCache or a win32 port of MemCache.

Answer (score 4):

What about checking out [Microsoft Velocity](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/velocity)?
Another option if you don't want to start using Microsoft CTP-ware is to check out [Nache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) which allows distributed cache/session state management

Answer (score 3):

Dare Obasanjo has a [pretty good blog](http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/2007/07/05/ASPNETCachingVsMemcachedSeekingEfficientDataPartitioningLookupAndRetrieval.aspx) post about this topic. You really need to assess what it is you're caching, why you're caching it and what your needs are before you can make a decision on a caching strategy.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.danga.com/memcached/

worked awesome for me and have heard nothing but goodness about it

Answer (score 1):

Another open source choice other than memcached probably worth looking into is Shared Cache. I haven't played with it. But it says to have c# native implementation.