# Is it better to store query results in memory, or run the same query multiple times?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I know little to nothing about DB optimization / memory management.

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT Value
FROM ValueTable
WHERE SomeConstraint > 4
```

I need to get the results from this query, as well as the results from this query with one additional WHERE clause. Which of these two approaches is better?

1) Select the results from that query into a variable. Then have two additional queries

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(VALUES))
FROM @SavedQuery

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(VALUES))
FROM @SavedQuery
WHERE otherConstraintColumn < 30
```

2)

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Value))
    FROM ValueTable
    WHERE SomeConstraint > 4

    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Value))
    FROM ValueTable
    WHERE SomeConstraint > 4
    AND otherConstraintColumn < 30
```

This would potentially be written in LINQ, so that may be how we store the results of the query.

Comment: As you will use the cached querey for just doing a count, a count in the database is pretty much efficient than retrieving the results and counting in memory. I would go for option 2 for sure.

Comment: This question is almost impossible to answer as it would be highly dependent on your specific needs and setup. How many rows are you returning? How slow is the latency between the DB and web server? How much memory/speed do you have on the web server? What are the specific responsiveness requirements for the web page? How many other queries are running concurrently? How many users hit this page simultaneously? I could ask a lot more, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: To quote Brent Ozar: "the fastest query is the one you never make". Although I agree with cyborg, it will all depend on your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example, approach #1 is more scalable (get your initial results, unfiltered, and re-filter them client-side using LINQ) but it is less efficient.
Keep in mind, that database servers are usually much better/faster/more-efficient at querying and filtering data.

Rule #1 is always: Do not abuse your DB.  So, put that advice ahead of anything else that I say.

When I look at your example, you only seem to be querying the database 2 times.  That is not abusive.  So, I'd say, go with approach #2 (two separate queries).  However, let me also qualify this advice: if you are running this block in a loop or if this code runs hundreds of times per day, I would change my advice.  2 re-queries is pretty light and inconsequential but there are plenty of conditions where it could be terrible.

---

Generally speaking, with regards to optimization, if you are using ASP.NET, it has some really nice caching mechanisms built-in.  They are better than storing query results in Session or Viewstate. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.90).aspx

If you are using winforms etc, storing results in memory will be worthwhile, as long as you aren't tight for memory.

Here is a SO article talking about several other popular approaches: [Best way to cache data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151/best-way-to-cache-data-in-net)

Comment: The linked question is a poor example of an SO question, as it's too opinion based. The article in one of the answers would be a much better reference: http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/2007/07/05/ASPNETCachingVsMemcachedSeekingEfficientDataPartitioningLookupAndRetrieval.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient approach would be to get both counts using a single query, for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(t.Value)) AS count1
     , COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN t.otherConstraintColumn<30 THEN t.Value END))) AS count2
  FROM ValueTable t
 WHERE t.SomeConstraint > 4
```

---

This approach will be less resource intensive on the database server than either of the other two approaches (either pulling a potentially large set of values from the database, or running two separate queries that access the same data.)

In terms of answering your question, between the two approaches, I would opt for the second one, pulling just the count from the database, rather than transferring a potentially large number of rows that will need to be processed again (on the client side), or materializing an (unnecessary) temporary store of the resultset (on the server side), and running additional queries against that.

The first query you show isn't going to have sufficient data to satisfy the subsequent queries, you'd also need to pull an indicator for `otherConstraintColumn<30` condition, in order for that to be used to satisfy the result. And to further reduce the number of rows that need to be transferred to the client (or materialized as a temporary table) on the server:

It would be more efficient to get this result set:

```
SELECT t.Value
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t.otherConstraintColumn < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS occlt30
  FROM ValueTable t
 WHERE t.SomeConstraint > 4
 GROUP BY t.Value
```

But that approach is still going to be much less efficient than just getting the actual resultset you need with a single query.